# brew: how to include path when building formula

Tags: ruby, macos, homebrew

I just installed a Formula mumps using

> brew install mumps.rb

and I got an output:

> ==> Caveats
>   MUMPS was built with shared libraries. If required,
>   static libraries are available in
>     /usr/local/opt/mumps/libexec/lib
>   You built a sequential MUMPS library.
>   Please add /usr/local/opt/mumps/libexec/include to the include path
>   when building software that depends on MUMPS.

When I try to install another Formula that depends on mumps I got error:

> Error: No available formula with the name "/usr/local/opt/mumps/.brew/mumps.rb"

Is this due to the Caveats above? If so, how can I include the path when installing the Formula that depends on mumps?

Answer (score 1):

No, the error message

> Error: No available formula with the name
>   "/usr/local/opt/mumps/.brew/mumps.rb"

might mean either `mumps` was not installed completely by Homebrew or is not linked.

### Specify Formula Dependency

If your application needs MUMPS to function, then in the formula simply declare a dependency

```
class YourFormula < Formula
  desc "Description of Your Formula"
  homepage "https://www.brew.sh"
  url "https://download.brew.sh/yourformula-1.2.3.tar.xz"
  sha256 "911e29e302252c96128965ee1f4067d5431a88e00ad1023a8bc1d6b922af5715"

  depends_on "mumps"
```

If your formula only need to run MUMPS commands during installation only, but do not necessarily need MUMPS when it is being used, then you can declare MUMPS as a build dependency

```
  depends_on "mumps" => :build
```

### Include Library and Header files during Compilation

I am assuming you need the MUMPS libraries located at `/usr/local/opt/mumps/libexec/lib` and the header files at `/usr/local/opt/mumps/libexec/include` during compilation.

In your formula's `install` section, you probably want to include the paths with the following command

```
system "./configure", 
        "--prefix=#{prefix}",
        "CFLAGS=-I$(brew --prefix)/opt/mumps/include",
        "LDFLAGS=-L$(brew --prefix)/opt/mumps/lib"
```

Answer (score 1):

I just want to provide a different "answer" (read: hack) to work around issues like these. I was trying to build squashfuse with brew, which has both been disabled since version 0.1.104, and depends on no-longer-supported macFUSE due to some license issues I believe.

I wanted to get squashfuse to build against the up-to-date version of macFUSE that I had downloaded from the official site. This version installs its header files in `/usr/local/include/fuse`, and I needed the brew squashfuse to build against those.

The approach suggested by Hanxue here didn't work for me. I'm not sure if the `CDFLAGS` env var is just not passed on or unsupported by the compiler or what's going on, but either way adding `/usr/local/include/fuse` as include path had no effect.

Instead, I hacked my way around it by symlinking the macFUSE header files into the homebrew include dir. That is,

```
cd $(brew --prefix)/include
for f in /usr/local/include/fuse/*.h; do ln -s $f; done
```

Now, I can build squashfuse, but of course only after removing the blocking logic from the formula file. That is, you need to `nano $(brew --prefix)/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/Formula/squashfuse.rb` and remove the three-line `on mac_os do` section at the top that quits with the "won't install wah wah" notice.

Of course, to be able to the compile, you also need to make sure `brew` doesn't automatically undo the changes you just made, so you run it like `HOMEBREW_NO_AUTO_UPDATE=1 brew upgrade squashfuse`.

Well, that's my command, as I already had an old version installed. You may need to add `--ignore-dependencies` depending on your formula and what you're trying to do if you're installing from scratch. E.g. with squashfuse, I'd assume brew will try to install its own (deprecated and/or disabled) version of macFUSE/osxfuse unless `--ignore-dependencies` is added.